# How to combine waveform data file (.mseed)?

Tags: python

I am using Obspy a python package to download the earthquake data on hourly basis. Obspy package, download 3 files for each hour with same name except the component N, E, Z. For example: 6D.ABR8..HHN__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ABR8..HHE__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ABR8..HHZ__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed

I used the following script to merge these files:

```
import obspy
input_fnames = [f"6D.ABR8..HH{c}__20041201T000001Z.mseed" for c in list("ENZ")]
output_fname = "combined.mseed"

traces = []
for file in input_fnames:
  stream = obspy.read(file)
  traces.append(stream[0])
combined = obspy.Stream(traces)
combined.write(output_fname, format="MSEED")
```

May someone suggest me how I can to modify this script for bulk of data with different files names.

Example file names and expected output file names are as as follows:

```
#First set of files
6D.ABR8..HHN__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ABR8..HHE__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ABR8..HHZ__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed

#expected output
6D.ABR8.__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 

#second set of files
6D.ASR8..HHN__20061201T000001Z__20061201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ASR8..HHE__20061201T000001Z__20061201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ASR8..HHZ__20061201T000001Z__20061201T060001Z.mseed
#expected output
6D.ASR8.__20061201T000001Z__20061201T060001Z.mseed

# third set of files
6D.YAR8..HHN__20081201T000001Z__20081201T060001Z.mseed 6D.YAR8..HHE__20081201T000001Z__20081201T060001Z.mseed 6D.YAR8..HHZ__20081201T000001Z__20081201T060001Z.mseed
# expected output
#6D.YAR8.__20081201T000001Z__20081201T060001Z.mseed
```

Thank you!

Comment: Didn't you ask a near identical question that was closed? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75275038/how-to-combine-mseed-files-with-different-components

Answer (score -1):

You could modify your script like:

```py
import obspy
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import re

parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("input_files", nargs="+", help="input mseed files to be combined")
args = parser.parse_args()

input_fnames = args.input_files
output_fname = re.sub("\.HH[NEZ]", "", args.input_files[0])

traces = []
for file in input_fnames:
  stream = obspy.read(file)
  traces.append(stream[0])
combined = obspy.Stream(traces)
combined.write(output_fname, format="MSEED")
```

and name it as `process.py`, then use it like:

```bash
python process.py 6D.ABR8..HHN__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ABR8..HHE__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed 6D.ABR8..HHZ__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed
# The output file will be saved into 6D.ABR8.__20041201T000001Z__20041201T060001Z.mseed
```